# Emmet - Notepad++ "Unknown exception"

Tags: python, notepad++, emmet

Every time I'm trying to use [Emmet's `Expand Abbreviation`](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/expand-abbreviation/) it gives me errors. First a pop up with `Unknown Exception` and then another pop up with `python script plugin did not accept the script`.

I tried reinstalling Notepad++ but that didn't help.

I'm running Windows 8 x64 & Notepad++ 6.6.9. This is the first time I'm using Emmet, after recently used the old Zen Coding. (Which works flawlessly.)

I have python 2.7 installed, if that necessary too.

Comment: This question may be better for: http://superuser.com/

Comment: You should file a bug on the Emmet bug tracker

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek sorry, i'm newb here :/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.
This is the solution which worked for me:

- `emmetio/npp` Bug ID #12: [*python script plugin did not accept the script*](https://github.com/emmetio/npp/issues/12)

Basically, the problem lies in the *Python Script* plugin which will be automatically installed with Emmet.

Go to this link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%200.9.2.0/
and download PythonScript_**full**_0.9.2.0 package.

Replace Notepad++'s Python package with PythonScript_**full**_0.9.2.0 and unpack the archive in Notepad++'s MAIN directory. (This is where `notepad++.exe` is.)
(Do NOT unpack the archive inside the `plugins` directory. That will not work. The `python27.dll` file needs to be in the same directory where `notepad++.exe` is.)

I am using Notepad++ v6.6.9 and it works now.

Comment: Just update to "last version" at http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/?source=navbar

Comment: Just wanted to note that you can just "merge" the plugin folder and overwrite any files with the same name.

Comment: If you're using the archived PythonScript zip from SourceForge, don't replace the PythonScript.dll and the PythonScript.chm file in the installation directory, as the ones that Notepad++ installs are likely newer. Just grab the PythonScript folder with all the libraries and put it in the install directory of Notepad++.

Answer (score 9):

There is a newer version (PythonScript_1.0.8.0.msi ) available here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/latest/download?source=files

I had the exact same issue on two different computers, one Windows 7 and one Windows 8, both 64bit. I installed the MSI on the Win8 computer and it fixed the problem.

Comment: PythonScript_full_0.9.2.0 didn't work for me on Windows 8.1 64, but the MSI did. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if it might be just the shortcut keys that aren't working by going to `menuBar>plugins>emmet>expandAbbreviation`. If clicking on that works after typing in some `emmet` syntax, but not when you type the shortcut key, reassign the shortcut keys. Here's what I did:

Look specifically at 
`menuBar>settings>shortcutMapper`

under `Main Menu-> "Insert Blank Line Above Current"`

and see that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> is already assigned there.

Change that to something else (I did <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>), and you'll see that your shortcut keys are working for `emmet`.

Comment: ran into that issue along with the python script error.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 objects (2 files and 2 directories) that you have to sort:

- Put the `python27.dll` file into the MAIN directory like so: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\notepad++\python27.dll`
- Put the others (`doc` directory, `PythonScript` directory, `PythonScript.dll` file) into `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\notepad++\plugins\`.

This works for Windows 8.

Also change the key shorcut by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or some other.