# In Notepad++, how can I insert the current date and time?

Tags: datetime, notepad++

On Windows Notepad.exe, I simply press <kbd>F5</kbd> and it inserts the date and time like this:

> 11:05 AM 1/14/2015

Can I add similarly simple functionality to Notepad++?

Comment: This isn't a programming related question..

Comment: There are some similar questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/299796/how-to-insert-time-and-date-and-the-directory-path-in-notepad).  If this exact question doesn't exist there, you can ask it there.

Comment: interesting point, do questions on programming/development tools qualify for SO questions?

Comment: @jxramos: They do. There's just not a whole lot of "programming" to be had here though. I mean, you don't usually use an IDE like Visual Studio for anything *but* development, whereas Notepad++ advertises itself as both a code editor and a straight-up Notepad replacement.

Comment: F5 does not work in Notepad on Windows 10 (neither does [the ".LOG" trick](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/909/windows-notepad-insert-time-and-date-into-text-or-log-file/)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I just verified that F5 still works today on my Windows 10 box. '11:51 AM 2019-03-22'.

Comment: Works on my Win10 box as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This features has been added in Notepad++ v8.1.4.

Menu > Edit > Insert >

- Date Time (short)
- Date Time (long)

That answers this question without the need for a plugin.

Can you find a way to map it to a shortcut? Currently, the shortcut mapper does not have an entry to map it to. When I try to record and playback a macro for it, I get gibberish on the screen (looks like a bug).

Comment: I've recorded a macro using the macro recording feature and then saved this macro with keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+D, now when I use this key combination, it inserts the current date/time at the cursor position.

Answer (score 66):

If your Notepad++ shipped with TextFX, you can find this in **TextFX > TextFX Insert > Date & Time - short format**, which will insert a string in the exact same format. If you don't see a TextFX menu, install it via the plugin manager and it will appear.

You can then bind it to a keyboard shortcut in **Settings > Shortcut Mapper... > Plugin Commands**. Look for **I:Date & Time - short format** in the mappings.

Comment: Can't find this plugin. Please link or update your answer.

Comment: @not2qubit: See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 65):

```
Step 1 : Install plugin TextFX
Step 2 : Insert Date & time
```

[image: Insert Date & Time in Notepad++]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Well explained!!

Comment: Looks like TextFX may now come as standard?? I didn't have to install it on my system, but part 2 of these instructions worked for me.

Answer (score 53):

## Try "Python Script" plugin

I prefer to use the *Python Script* plugin as documented here: https://ardamis.com/2014/03/09/adding-an-insert-datestamp-or-timestamp-macro-to-notepad-plus-plus/
because it gives me total control over how I want to the datetime stamp formatting to look, and it also allows me to create macro scripts for inserting other types of values that I want to compute.

### Install "Python Script" MANUALLY

Please note that you must download the Python Script plugin from http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/download.shtml because downloading it from the Plugin Manager in Notepad++ doesn't always work. (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110973/emmet-notepad-unknown-exception) for details.)

### Write "Time.py" script

Then you can write a simple script like this:

```
import time
# import sys
timeStr = time.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d' + ' @ ' + '%I:%M %p' )
# sys.stdout.write(timeStr)
editor.addText( timeStr )
```

You can change the format string as you wish. This allows you to have total control over the text output. (See [Python 2's `time.strftime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for details.)

Then save the script to this filename:

> "%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts\Time.py"

### Create "menu item" inside "Python Script"

Navigate here: `Menu bar -> Plugins -> Python Script -> Configuration` like this:

[image: Click on configuration]

Then you can add the script like this:

[image: Add script to config]

### Assign hotkey

Then, when you restart Notepad++, you can assign the script to a shortcut like this by going to `Menu bar -> Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin Commands -> Time`:

[image: Add keyboard shortcut to Notepad++]

### Further reading

More documentation on the *Python Script* plugin is available here: [PythonScript plugin documentation for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/)

Comment: Since TextFX dosen't work anymore with new versions of notepad++, this solution works on new 64 bit notepad++, thank you!

Comment: For installing, i found these instructions to work (i.e. to be up-to-date) for a 64-bit install: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above

Comment: I would +100 if it was possible! Once you install PythonScript and start using it (cca 20 minutes to get comfortable) you will never go back to the old ways!

Comment: I would just say to try the Plugins Admin first.  It is almost instant, very easy, seems like it should be the best integration.  as of 2019 I have tried it on a dozen systems including an Ubuntu snap install and it has always worked flawlessly.

Comment: Great answer. For assigning hotkeys, Time wasn't showing up in the Plugin Commands. So I had to first go to the Plugins --> Python Script --> Configuration and add Time.py to the "Menu" box. After restarting Notepad++, Time.py showed up in plugin commands.

Answer (score 10):

In one of the recent N++ updates, my previous shortcut of `CTRL + SHIFT + D`, stopped working. I then rechecked and had to remap the *custom date* shortcut to `ALT+ SHIFT + D`. This is how it looks:

[image]

Make sure your customized date match your expectations:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the `TextFX` plugin [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108418/452096) is not available for 64bit any more.

[The alternative as of today](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14961/notepad-64bit-inserting-timestamps/12) is to install the `Notepad++ Plugin Demo` plugin, which provides `Date Time - short format` and `Date Time - long format`. Map to shortcuts as desired. In my German locale, the results are, respectively:

```
12:10 01.07.2020
12:10 Mittwoch, 1. Juli 2020
```

Comment: Thanks, it's easier than writing a python script, like the currently most upvoted alternative answer to TextFX suggests.Let's hope this demo plugin will stay that way...

Answer (score 5):

With the TextFx add on there's an option to insert date and time. I guess you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

[image: Time formats with TextFx Notepad++ addon]

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Notepad++ 8.1.5, you can insert a custom date/time format using `Edit/Insert/Date Time (customized)`. You can customize it in `Settings/Preferences/Multi-Instance & Date`.

Comment: Of course, you can also assign a keyboard shortcut to this command, such as `ALT+ENTER`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method through LuaScript (https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/497 and https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html): install LuaScript plugin first, then in LuaScript Edit Startup Script past the following:

```
npp.AddShortcut("Insert Current Date/Time", "Ctrl+Shift+D", function()
    editor:ReplaceSel(os.date("%I:%M %p %m/%d/%Y"))
end)
```

After restart npp, the Ctrl-Shift-D will do as F5 in notepad.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer using "Autohotkey":

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/21387-how-to-insert-current-date-into-a-hotkey/

Examples:

```
;//will replace ddd keystroke with yyyy-MM-dd formatted date
:R*?:ddd:
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyy-MM-dd
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return

;//will replace ttt keystroke with yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm formatted date/time
:R*?:ttt::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

Comment: Autohotkey is like a Swiss Army Knife. Unquestionably a "required tool" and every single power user should be using it! Been using it for about two years now and I can't believe I overlooked it for so long. Thanks for the script!

Comment: this video show this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQBEira6ZMQ
I prefer using AutoHotkey 
you can add it to your startup folder as mentioned here : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-cool-autohotkey-scripts-make/#adsninja-ad-zone-adsninja-ad-unit-characterCountRepeatable-636c2cc1cf2a8-REPEAT3

Answer (score 1):

Click native "Menu->Edit->Insert->Date time"

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1368s.png

Bind to key in "Menu->Settings->Shortcut mapper"

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an easy and flexible way to insert a date/time stamp in any format you like.**

Like many other developers, I used the FingerText plugin which allows you to insert customizable snippets of code or text by typing a "trigger" word and pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

One of my snippets is to insert a date/time stamp that I use in code comments:

I just type `stamp`<kbd>tab</kbd> and it inserts a date like this: `2020-07-31 @ 11:45`

Here is the FingerText code I use to generate the stamp, which you can modify for any datetime format you choose:

```
$[![(key)DATE:yyyy-MM-dd]!] @ $[![(key)TIME:HH:mm]!] $[0[]0][>END<]
```

You can download FingerText through the Plugins Admin dialog.

Comment: Looks cool, but it appears that the zip file to install FingerText points to a dead SourceForge link. So I can't install FingerText.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the project is dead, but I still find it very useful. Is it not available through the Plugins Admin dialog? You can also download it directly from https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/fingertext/Alpha%20Releases/FingerText%20-%200.5.60.zip

Comment: I get a 502 for that link. Maybe it's my firewall? The Plugins Admin uses the same link.  Thanks for the suggestions. It does look cool.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I just confirmed it worked for me. Here is a direct link to one of the sourceforge mirrors: https://managedway.dl.sourceforge.net/project/fingertext/Alpha%20Releases/FingerText%20-%200.5.60.zip    And failing that, well, if you don't mind downloading a binary from a random person on the internet, I uploaded it to https://filebin.net/984d8v81rsgh59xo and the link will last for a week.