# Notepad++ Regex + python script (addition in the replace)

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I got quite the same problem of this guy "[Notepad++ Regular Expression add up numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506990/notepad-regular-expression-add-up-numbers/35365318#35365318)" i don't know python (shame on me maybe). I got an array :

```
$_ArrFinal = array("A"=>1, "B" =>2, "C" => 3, "D" => 4, "E"=>4, "F" => "5",...)
```

I have simplify it but i need to increment all the value above 4 in this array by 1.
So i did this like in the answer, but sadly it doesn't seems to work :

```
def calculate(match):
        return '=>%s)' %(match.group(1)+1)
editor.rereplace('=>([5-9]|[1-9]\d{1,})', calculate)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Well, I get exceptions all the time, maybe it is a good idea to [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110973/emmet-notepad-unknown-exception) approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the default Python Script installation is not working well. This is what has just worked for me:

- Install [Python Script 1.0.8.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0/)
- Go to the *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*
- Select the file name (say, "increment_numbers.py")
- Place this script there:

Code:

```
def calculate(match):
    return '%s%s'%(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))+1))

editor.rereplace(r'(=>\s*"?)(\d+)', calculate)
```

Then, just evoke this 'increment_numbers' script.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL4wP4/2). The expression matches:

- `(=>\s*"?)` - Group 1, `=>` followed with zero or more whitespace symbols (`\s*`) followed with an optional `"` (as `?` matches one or zero preceding token)
- `(\d+)` - Group 2, one or more digits

Comment: It's weird but plugin I installed by Plugin Managed (ver 1.0.6.0) seemed not to work but this one (1.0.8.0) worked well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 1.0.8.0 works well, that is why I always suggest installing that one.