# Replace specific word with increment counter in notepad++ - define start point for counter

Tags: notepad++

Can I do this using notepad++ ?

```
Bnnr - Details : 
Name : Top90
Size : 468 x 60
file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/t/top90-468x60.gif
Telegram : @BannerDesigner
Phone : +989014131211

Bnnr - Details : 
Name : Frootel
Size : 468 x 60
file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/f/frootel-468x60.gif
Telegram : @BannerDesigner
Phone : +989014131211
```

To

```
12 - Bnnr - Details : 
Name : Top90
Size : 468 x 60
file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/t/top90-468x60.gif
Telegram : @BannerDesigner
Phone : +989014131211

13 - Bnnr - Details : 
Name : Frootel
Size : 468 x 60
file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/f/frootel-468x60.gif
Telegram : @BannerDesigner
Phone : +989014131211
```

For example starting point is 12 ,

So i want to add increment counter for each specific phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Regex + python script (addition in the replace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366602/notepad-regex-python-script-addition-in-the-replace)

Comment: You might want to transform the records into csv and then approach the problem from within a spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi my friends , Thank you for your helpful guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for an existing answer before posting, please.
[Notepad++ incrementally replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace)

TL;DR - in notepad++ no, you cannot, but you can in Sublime or TextPad etc.

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done within current funcionality and without requiring extra plugins or tools.

1. Place at the beginning of the record and press Edit->Column Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
2. Use: "Number to insert", Initial number => 12, Increase by => 1, Repeat => 7 (7 is because of the number of lines for every record)
3. You'll get this result

   ```
   12Bnnr - Details : 
   12Name : Top90
   12Size : 468 x 60
   12file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/t/top90-468x60.gif
   12Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   12Phone : +989014131211
   12
   13Bnnr - Details : 
   13Name : Frootel
   13Size : 468 x 60
   13file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/f/frootel-468x60.gif
   13Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   13Phone : +989014131211
   ```
4. Now we will remove the numbers that are not needed. Launch search and replace. Mark the 'regular expressions' and Search: `^\d++(?!Bnnr - Details)`, Replace by `(nothing)`. You will get:

   ```
   12Bnnr - Details : 
   Name : Top90
   Size : 468 x 60
   file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/t/top90-468x60.gif
   Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   Phone : +989014131211

   13Bnnr - Details : 
   Name : Frootel
   Size : 468 x 60
   file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/f/frootel-468x60.gif
   Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   Phone : +989014131211
   ```
5. Now, fix the first line. Search `^(\d++)(?=Bnnr - Details)`, replace by `\1 -` to get the final result:

   ```
   12 - Bnnr - Details : 
   Name : Top90
   Size : 468 x 60
   file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/t/top90-468x60.gif
   Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   Phone : +989014131211

   13 - Bnnr - Details : 
   Name : Frootel
   Size : 468 x 60
   file : https://i-d.ir/ad/banners/gif/2014/f/frootel-468x60.gif
   Telegram : @BannerDesigner
   Phone : +989014131211
   ```

Bear in mind that you can merge steps 4 & 5 within a single click using notepad macros. So you can apply the same thing later more easily. For example:

[image: Procedure while recording a macro]